# Java проверить на валидность comma separated values через regex

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, валидация, bean-validation

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class A {

     @Pattern(regexp = "")
     private String values;

     // getter and setter

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        A a = new A();
        a.setValues("name1:value1,name2:value,name10:value7");

        Set<ConstraintViolation<A>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(a);
        System.out.println(constraintViolations.size());
        System.out.println(constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
    }
}
```

> Поле `private String values;` содержит comma separated values (name:value, ...,...). Где "name" и "value" не должны повторяться. Разделитель ","

**Как проверить на языке java валидность через один regex используя @Pattern ?:**

1. **Если Comma separated values валиден - содержит правильную структуру "name1:value1,name2:value,name10:value7"**
2. **Если "name" не повторяеться**

Comment: Что у вас уже получилось?

Comment: |regex1 = ([^,(])+((?=:)|(.\\)) - Выбираю все "name"|

|regex2 = ([^,(])+((?=,)|(\\*)) - Выбираю все "name:value"|

|regex3 = \b(\w+)\b\s*(?=.*\b\1\b) - Проверяю если в список "name1, name2, ..." не повторяються "name"|

****Как я могу объединить результат regex1 со следующим регулярным выражением?****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class A {

     @Pattern(regexp = "^(([A-Za-z0-9]+):[A-Za-z0-9+/=]+(?!.*,\2:)(,|$))*$")
     private String values;

     // getter and setter

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        A a = new A();
        a.setValues("name1:value1,name2:value,name10:value7");

        Set<ConstraintViolation<A>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(a);
        System.out.println(constraintViolations.size());
        System.out.println(constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^((\w+):\w+(?!.*,\2:)(,|$))+$
```

Для проверки (в браузере под `\w` подойдут только латинские буквы, цифры и подчёркивания, джава должна сделать правильно):

```css
input { outline: none; border: 1px solid; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
:valid { border-color: green; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input pattern="^((\w+):\w+(?!.*,\2:)(,|$))+$" autofocus>
```

Comment: Извините, я ошибся. Ваш ответ хороший, но он не работает для моего сценария. Ваш regex не проходит если как значение ставить и символы (name1:abc345dddzzFgQ/789Q==)

Comment: @Andrei, ну так замени `\w` на набор нужных символов. Для base64 будет `[A-Za-z0-9+/=]`. В принципе, можно более точно проверить корректность значения, если подумать.

Comment: Спасибо за вас хороший ответ. Он мне помог.